# OnLoad Event of GWT Widget like TextBox, TextArea

Tags: events, gwt

I want to catch the `onLoad` Event of `TextBox`. But I am not finding any handler through which I can call it. GWT provides `LoadHandler` for the same purpose. But I don't know how should I instantiate the Load Event from `TextBox`.

Any help would be appreciable!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBox extends [ValueBoxBase](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html) which has a protected method called [onLoad()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html#onLoad%28%29).

All you have to do is the following

```
public class MyTextBox extends TextBox
{

  @Override
  protected void onLoad() {
   //Do your stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for [addAttachHandler()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/HasAttachHandlers.html#addAttachHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.AttachEvent.Handler%29) .

If you are designing an `custom textbox` implement the interface [HasAttachHandlers](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/HasAttachHandlers.html) .

Answer (score -1):

```
textBox.addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
   if (event.isAttached()){

     doMyOnLoadMethod();

   }
  }
});
```